# Reinstall OS X (Yosemite) without Internet Connection

Tags: install

I have got very slow internet connection. Last time, it took me 8 hours to download the Yosemite installation files.
Is there anyway to clone a clean copy of OS X to another drive?

I have tried rsync in the Terminal after Bootup + Option. The rsync command is not available

Comment: Next time, remember to copy the installer over to another drive, so the install doesn't delete it.

Comment: btw, did you try Recovery? Cmd/R at boot.

Comment: Don't shout. Rolled back edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a third-party utility like [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) or you can even use Disk Utility in OS X to create and restore OS X Images.  There is also **hdiutil** and **asr** if you want to work from the command line.  In a Terminal type `man hdiutil` and `man asr` to bring up their man pages.

Comment: I have seen "How to Make a Bootable Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10 USB Thumb Drive" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQurLY61EtA). What's the point creating a Bootable USB thumb drive? This drive takes 5.6GB. Booting from such a drive, you still need to download the installation file from the internet. No point in preparing that at all

Comment: You can't install without an installer - you have to download it once… the trick is not to lose it.

Comment: Nope. You have to use the internet by all means

Comment: @Hoy Cheung, you are wrong!  If you've created the USB installer properly you do not need to re-download to install!

Comment: @user3439894, thanks for the suggestion. Can you provide the command for hdiutil? I am not very interested in any third-party utilities, since I need to create a clean copy.

Comment: OK. I have found this page: https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201372. I will try this first.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I totally agree the trick is definitely not to lose the installer, given the way Apple pulled the Mavericks installer from the App Store. I also think it's equally important to make a USB installer and put it somewhere safe, so you'll always have the ability to reinstall whether you have network access or not...

Comment: Thank you guys. I was misled by a staff in the genius bar. He said I couldn't create an installer and refused to help me to make one. But now I have succeeded to create one by following this page - support.apple.com/en-au/HT201372

Comment: @Hoy Cheung, Since Apple has a "Create a bootable installer for OS X Mavericks or Yosemite" document at their website I find it utterly ridiculous that the person helping you at the Apple store would refuse to help.  I would complain to the management of that store as there is no good excuse that you were not properly helped!

Comment: I just wonder how Time Machine works? Is it an application that can recover the OS image before the computer boots into OS X? Should I still work with hdiutil?